# Pydev, can't import pylab? WindowsError: [Error 5] Access denied

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib, pydev

I'm trying to use Python with Eclipse and PyDev.

I can import several packages, e.g. numpy. But when I want to import pylab to plot some functions, I get a `WindowsError: [Error 5] Access denied`.

When I click on `Window>Preferences>PyDev>Interpreters>Python Interpreter`  in Eclipse I can see that PyDev found all my libaries. Since I've installed [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) the Pylab package is already installed.

When I add pylab as a forced builtin I still get the same error.

Here is the full error report

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\scripts\test\test\test.py", line 1, in <module>
import pylab as pl
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
from matplotlib.pylab import *
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 269, in <module>
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 98, in <module>
_backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line    28, in pylab_setup
globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4agg.py", line 13, in <module>
from backend_qt4 import QtCore, QtGui, FigureManagerQT, FigureCanvasQT,\
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt4.py", line 21, in <module>
import matplotlib.backends.qt4_editor.figureoptions as figureoptions
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt4_editor\figureoptions.py", line 13, in <module>
import matplotlib.backends.qt4_editor.formlayout as formlayout
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt4_editor\formlayout.py", line 51, in <module>
from matplotlib.backends.qt4_compat import QtGui,QtCore
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\qt4_compat.py", line 80, in <module>
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, __version__, __version_info__
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PySide\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
_setupQtDirectories()
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PySide\__init__.py", line 11, in _setupQtDirectories
pysideDir = _utils.get_pyside_dir()
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 93, in get_pyside_dir
return _get_win32_case_sensitive_name(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(QtCore.__file__)))
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 84, in _get_win32_case_sensitive_name
path = _get_win32_long_name(_get_win32_short_name(s))
 File "C:\Programme\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PySide\_utils.py", line 74, in _get_win32_long_name
raise WinError()

WindowsError: [Error 5] Zugriff verweigert
```

Comment: Something is borked in your PySide installation. Are you sure all of the files exist and you have permission at access them (can you even control file access in windows?)?

Comment: Seems like my installation of Anaconda failed...

Comment: Try running your app with administrative privilege.  Then try removing and re-installing Anaconda (pydev is probably OK).  Python is not opening libraries in write mode, but you might not have directory traverse permission or something arcane.